# Include textbox within option tag in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I want to include a dropdown in my HTML page where I intend to allow user input also. This question is different from many others on stack overflow asking to add an option altogether.

I have a list of tech indicators in the dropdown. But what I need is when the user selects Simple Moving Average, he/she may also be able to input the desired value for period of SMA. But as far as I have searched, there seems no way to include a textbox within an option tag.

I am ok to use third party plugins like bootstrap/select2. Does anyone have any idea reagarding how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Adding of textbox inside native dropdown box is not possible. but you can add another textbox. when certain value selected you can display that textbox to get data. I just found out a fiddle according to your requirements.
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/DZ7dc/)

Comment: this fiddle does not use select. I was wondering if its possible using select tag.

Comment: You can't put a textbox inside the select.